# PostgreSQL 10 Optimizing slow query performance with aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, array

I have two tables person and tag.
person has an bigint[] column containing ids of tags.
I want to write a query which fetches all tags including the count of the tagged persons.
So far I have the following query

```
SELECT t.id AS id, t.name AS name,
(select count(id) from person where person.tags @> array[t.id]) as instances_count
 FROM tag AS t
```

I know the sub-query is bad but I couldn't think of a way of doing it better.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you

Edit:
PostgreSQL 10.8

Here is the 'explain analyze':

```
Seq Scan on tag t  (cost=0.00..4309761.27 rows=79 width=41) (actual time=131.109..11329.945 rows=79 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=560506 read=3505230
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=54553.91..54553.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=143.411..143.412 rows=1 loops=79)
          Buffers: shared hit=560505 read=3505230
          ->  Seq Scan on person i  (cost=0.00..54550.82 rows=1233 width=8) (actual time=41.367..143.393 rows=148 loops=79)
                Filter: ((NOT is_deleted) AND (tags @> ARRAY[t.id]))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 245452
                Buffers: shared hit=560505 read=3505230
Planning time: 0.098 ms
Execution time: 11330.014 ms
```

Comment: Please edit to include an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, and see https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for how ask effective performance questions.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need an index on the array:

```
create index on person using gin (tags);
```

It is not obvious to me that the subselect is worse than any other way of accomplishing the same thing.

Your query plan doesn't match your query text, "is_deleted" occurs in the plan but not the text.  If you want to optimize for that you could do:

```
create index on person using gin (tags) where not is_deleted;
```

How important that is depends on what fraction of your table is_deleted.

---

An alternative method not needing the index would be

```
select * from 
    (select unnest(tags) as id, count(id) from person group by 1) agg 
join 
    tag 
using (id);
```

But this would not return any tags which had a count of zero.  You could make the join a right join, but then reported count would be null rather than zero.

Comment: creating the index lowered the execution time to 13.437 ms. thank you